# Add new row at top fxml tableview

Tags: javafx, row, tableview, addition

I am able to add new row at below the existing row but I want to add new row at top of the existing row.

Is is possible with JavaFX? If yes then could you please guide me how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us say that the `TableView` has items set to an ObservableList `data`.

```
tableView.setItems(data);
```

When we need to add a `new element` at the top of the tableview, we add it to the top of the `ObservableList`. In order to add an element to top of the list we add it at `index 0` using the [add(index, element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true#add-int-E-) :

```
data.add(0, newItem);
```